# Splicing mRNA using for a while loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, splice

I am taking a coding class in Python 3 and I need help figuring out what is wrong with my code. Basically what I am doing is taking an mRNA sequence and splicing out the exons in the sequence. I give the function a sequence and the location of the exons, and then it has to splice them out and return the string of mRNA. The point of the assignment is we are not supposed to use list comprehensions, split, or join methods. Here is what I have so far:

```
def splice(seq, exons):
    newseq = ""
    i = 0
    for x in exons:
        while i < len(seq):
            if i == x[0]:
                i += (x[1] - x[0])
            else:
                newseq += seq[i]
                i = i + 1
    return newseq
```

As it is right now, my code returns the mRNA sequence with only the first exon spliced out and not any of the others in the list of exon locations. Like this:

```
>> splice("AAACCCTTTTGGGTTTAA", [(3,6), (10,16)])
'AAATTTTGGGTTTAA'
```

It is supposed to return this (for my given example): 'AAATTTTAA'

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work? Thanks!
(Reminder that I have never coded before this semester except a tiny bit in Java, so please do not be too critical of me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def splice(seq, exons):
    newseq = ""
    next = 0
    for x, y in exons:
        newseq += seq[next:x]
        next = y
    newseq += seq[next:]        
    return newseq
```

And testing:

```
>>> splice("AAACCCTTTTGGGTTTAA", [(3,6), (10,16)])
'AAATTTTAA'
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what my code is supposed to do

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood. Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need to have a while loop. Here is a version using only the for loop:

```
def splice(seq, exons):
    newseq = ""
    i = 0
    n = 0
    for x in exons:
        newseq = seq[i:x[0]-n]+seq[x[1]-n:]
        seq = newseq
        n = x[1]-x[0]
        i = x[0] - n
    return newseq

splice("AAACCCTTTTGGGTTTAA", [(3,6), (10,16)])
```

Comment: This did not seem to work... Check my edit to my question